# "Collection id type is non-numeric or unknown. Can only generate numeric ids."

Tags: angular-in-memory-web-api

```
public createOEInputParameters(param: OeinputParameters) {
        const url = `${this.apiUrl}`;
        return this.http.post(url,  JSON.stringify( param), httpOptions).pipe(map(this.serviceHelper.extractData))
          .pipe(catchError(this.serviceHelper.handleError));
      })





Param model:
    export class OeinputParameters {
    public common: OEGenericInputParameter;
    public fleet: OEInputParameterWideBody[];
    public optional: OEInputParameterOptions;
    constructor() { }
}







in-memory Service Api:
     createDB(){
            const inputparamsfun = () =>{
            //what to be given here?
            }
            }
```

Expected result:
    need a post the form data which will be similar to json to in memory webapi. User gives details in the form.all the details are clubbed and made as param model